# JQuery Datepicker error after Postback with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

my Datepicker works fine, but after postback it doesn't work any more. I tried also pageLoad method but it still doesn't work.

I have a List of Items from database. If I click an item of the list, I get the information about it in a table from database (I used POST Method with Ajax).

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
      var pickerOpts = { dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM }; 
      $("#datepicker").datepicker(pickerOpts);
             });
</script>
```

Textfield:

```
echo("<input type='text' id='datepicker' value='$db[deadline]'>");
```

I've googled for hours but found nothing that worked for me.

EDIT NOTE: Errors after trying Rahil Wazir's help:

[image]

Comment: It seems you have not included the jquery datepicker library if it is included make sure its being call after jquery library.

Comment: @rahilWazir I've fixed that error. The only one is this: TypeError: $.datepicker is undefined
var pickerOpts = { dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM };

Comment: Does ajax pull a piece of data to replace or it replaces all dom elements?

Comment: Ajax only replace one div. The list above still stays.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var pickerOpts = { dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM }; //Place this inside below .on handler if this also updates.
    $(document).on('focus', '#datepicker', function(e){
        $(this).datepicker(pickerOpts);
    });
});
</script>
```

You have to use [`$(document).on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler when dom updates. And add event [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) to trigger the datepicker handler.

**Edited:**
See this [answer](/questions/11918991/typeerror-datepicker-is-undefined) for further help

Comment: I implemented it into my code but now the Datepicker doesn't work at all. I got the information about the list item from the page "about.php". So do I have to write the JQuery Function in the page where the list ("list.php") is or on the page where I get the information ("about.php")?

Comment: Copy `$(document)...` code in developer console and let me know if that works.

Comment: I've added the errors to the question. "auftraege.php" is my "list.php"